# building a structure of lists of strings with different size in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

What data structure is used to build a concatenation of lists of strings with different size?

E.g.,

```
a_list = ['h','i']
b_list = ['t','h','e','r','e']
c_list = ['fr', 'ie','nd']
```

desired structure:

```
my_structure = [ ['h','i'],
                 ['t','h','e','r','e'],
                 ['fr', 'ie','nd']
               ]
```

and then fill it in with 'null' strings to get the same size in every list:

```
 my_structure = [    ['h','i','null','null','null'],
                     ['t','h','e','r','e'],
                     ['fr', 'ie','nd','null', 'null']
                   ]
```

Comment: Do you want the string 'null', or do you want the null string?

Comment: does not matter, a random string, it is just to get every list with the same length!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
import itertools

np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(a_list, b_list, c_list, fillvalue='null'))).T

array([['h', 'i', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
      ['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'],
      ['fr', 'ie', 'nd', 'null', 'null']],
  dtype='<U4')
```

**Edit**: As per your comment that you want to add new lists to your array, it is probably more straightforward to create a list of the lists you want to use, and you can append to that list somewhat dynamically:

```
a_list = ['h','i']
b_list = ['t','h','e','r','e']
c_list = ['fr', 'ie','nd']

my_list = [a_list, b_list, c_list]

my_arr = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*my_list, fillvalue='null'))).T

>>> my_arr
array([['h', 'i', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
       ['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'],
       ['fr', 'ie', 'nd', 'null', 'null']],
      dtype='<U4')
```

Then you can add a new list to `my_list`:

```
d_list = ['x']

my_list.append(d_list)

my_arr = np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*my_list, fillvalue='null'))).T

>>> my_arr
array([['h', 'i', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
       ['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'],
       ['fr', 'ie', 'nd', 'null', 'null'],
       ['x', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']],
      dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: I think that would work. I got a question: if a need to add a new list to that array (let's say list_d) to that already built structure. How could I do it?

Comment: I think the most straightforward way would be to re-make your array: add `list_d` to your `zip_longest`. An alternative would be to pad `list_d` with `null` strings so that it is the same length as the longest element, and then use `np.vstack` or something like that, but it seems complicated, and wouldn't actually save you much performance.

Comment: the thing is that I have to concatenate the lists on the go in a loop since the lists are stored in different files. So I cannot really (a_list, b_list, c_list,....zzz_list) do that, I will have to append it one by one.. @sacul

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a list comprehension. It involves calculating the maximum length of your lists as an initial step:

```
L = (a_list, b_list, c_list)
maxlen = max(map(len, L))

res = [i+['null']*(maxlen-len(i)) for i in L]

print(res)

[['h', 'i', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
 ['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'],
 ['fr', 'ie', 'nd', 'null', 'null']]
```